# BoundsError: attempt to access 2n-element UnitRange{Int32} at index [2n+1]

Tags: julia, julia-gpu

I’m recently using Knet and working on a CNN.
I have a dataset-input of `20000 x 1 x 1 x 200000` which I use for training

As soon as i start training with `progress!(sgd(dtrn,ncycle(n)))`, I get following the error:

```
BoundsError: attempt to access 2n-element UnitRange{Int32} at index [2n+1]
```

depending on the batchsize * 2.
On my local computer the code is working fine, tested it and everything works with smaller dataset-examples. On the server, where Knet works fine, my code crashes tho.

Any suggestions how to fix?
Already tried different batchsizes but nothing seems to work.

Comment: It’s not seeing `n` as a variable and rather as a character it seems, can you link the full code?

Comment: the n is just a wildcard i put in there by hand to describe the problem. for example this happens when i use batchsize = 8:
attempt to access 16n-element UnitRange{Int32} at index [17]

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2ALcWVVV
Batchsize here is 1, the training continues to like 50% but then the error occurs with 

BoundsError: attempt to access 2-element UnitRange{Int32} at index [3]

Comment: It’s hard to tell without seeing any code, but Julia is 1 indexed so that may be a factor.

Comment: i posted the code on the link above. but i found the error, it was the outputlayer which had size 2. i forgot to changed it to 4, since i use 4 datasets now and not 2 anymore.

Comment: Can you add this as an answer to the question for completeness?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, it was the outputlayer which had size 2. I forgot to change it to 4, since I use 4 datasets now and not 2 anymore. Thanks to everyone investigating.